# What's the type of return value from generate_presigned_url in boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

```
presigned_url_list = [s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object',
                                            Params={'Bucket': bucket,
                                                    'Key': content['Key']},
                                            ExpiresIn=600)
                                            for content in file_list['Contents']]
 return presigned_url_list
```

I get the presigned url by the function.

And it works but the result like this:

```json
[
    "presigned url1",
    "presigned url2"
]
```

What's the type of return value?

I don't want to see [] and "" and the "," also.

I want to print it like this>

```
presigned url1
presigned url2
presigned url3
...
...
```

Answer (score 3):

The `[]`, quotes and commas are simply the way that Python is printing the list.

To get one URL per line, you could just print it with:

```py
for url in presigned_url_list:
  print(url)
```